# Docker Toolbox Wildfly IP Address HTTP 404 Response

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-toolbox

I have recently installed docker toolbox for windows 10 home. I downloaded the jboss/wildfly image from the docker hub. I tried to create the container with the following command.: 
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -it jboss/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement 0.0.0.0.` The server appears to be up and running. I got the IP address for my host using `docker-machine ls` which gave me an IP address of **192.168.99.100**. When I type the following into my MS Edge browser `http:\\192.168.99.100:8080\` instead of getting the wildfly welcome page I get “Cannot Reach This Page” error (HTTP 404?). I have tried this with the Tomcat server and have the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the build file on the docker registry, I would try `http://127.0.0.1:9990` or `http://192.168.99.100:9990`

Ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly

Comment: hi, still getting the 404 response

Comment: I noticed an error message when the VirtualBox VM (default) is first created when I access the quick start terminal for the first time. Got an error message saying "corrupt host adapter". The software appears to create another one.